# AppendChild to React Ref Object

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use the appendChild function to the react Ref Object in order to copy/clone a div inside a the Material-ui Carousel component.

**How I'm using the hook**

```
const stopsCorousel = React.createRef();
const nextStopsDiv = React.createRef();
```

**The function I'm calling**

```
const showNextStopDiv = ()=>{
     const corouselContainer = stopsCorousel.current;
     const sequelStopsDiv  = nextStopsDiv.current;
     let clone = sequelStopsDiv.cloneNode(true);
     clone.style.display='block';
     corouselContainer.appendChild(clone)
   }
```

**The thrown error**

`NewTripRequest.js:213 Uncaught TypeError: corouselContainer.appendChild is not a function`

[A demo on Repl.it](https://repl.it/@MoiseRwibutso/React-Carousel#src/App.js)

**The bigger picture in a Screenshot**

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox that reproduce the issue?

Comment: Apologies @MoshFeu, I got caught up and didn't provide a demo link in time. But I've updated the post and included the link but I couldn't use CodeSandBox coz it had issues I couldn't know why. Thanks

Comment: Could you explain your desired result? A mock-up graphic would also be helpful.

Comment: It seems odd that you have UI controls _inside_ your carousel. I would expect those to be outside in most cases. But I could imagine them being inside sometimes, just wanting to make sure that was the intent and not a typo.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner,  you're right, I think of using them outside the carousel, it's just that it was new to me. And my intent is  to have those 3 input fields added on the page each time I click the Add Stop button so that a user would use the carousel to use the multiple  input fields.

Comment: Looking at the docs and source though, if what you want is to programmatically change the active slide on the carousel when a button is clicked, it doesn't seem like that feature is supported. You can add a new slide to the carousel just fine (without needing refs), but it doesn't have a way to set the active slide.

Comment: So is the idea that the input fields would be the last slide in the carousel, like I mentioned above? I would consider an alternate UI though, because that would be easier to implement. Instead, consider  replacing or covering the carousel with the "new stop" controls. I believe that would be a simpler user experience as well.

Comment: Can you show an example with stops already added?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner, what I had achieved before but didn't like, adding the inputs vertically, which makes the form longer each time a user clicks the button to add the 3 input fields. So, I wanted to make it a slider to keep the page just the way it is.